# iOS Photo album "Open with..." Dialog API?

Tags: ios, api, photos

I was wondering if there is an API available for the "Open with" / share dialog. I see 3 social networks (Twitter, Facebook, and a JPN site) by default in iOS, but I was wondering if it was possible to register your own app to accept these options.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like UIActivityViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're asking. If you just want to present that Open With dialog, it's the UIActivityViewController. You can even implement your own custom UIActivity to appear *in* the dialog, but that will only appear if the user summons the activity view in *your* app.

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch26.html#_activity_view

If you're asking how your app can appear when the activity view is summoned in another app, if you export a document type in your Info.plist, your app will appear in the Open With dialog if the user starts with a document of that type.

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_document_types